# How to identify the charecterstic in Plugin.Ble?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I need to get the correct characteristic to read and write in Bluetooth device but among two characteristics, I am not able to predicate how to read the value using which characteristic.

> characteristic property type-->write/write response
>
> characteristic property type-> indicate

```
var services = await connectedDevice.GetServicesAsync();
var serviceid = services[0].Id;
var service = await connectedDevice.GetServiceAsync(serviceid);
var characteristics = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
var characteristicwrite = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(characteristics[0].Id);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
await characteristicwrite.WriteAsync(bytes);
var characteristicread = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(characteristics[1].Id);
```

In my predication, characteristic read is wrong and characteristic write is correct.

Please help me find the correct characteristic and descriptor.

Here is a screenshot for reference:

[image: characteristics image]

Comment: What do you mean by `characteristic read is wrong`?

Comment: I can't able to get the read characteristic property.

Comment: Did you get any error or just null?

Comment: I got only null

Comment: How about read the `characteristics[1].Id` first? You can create an issue on Github for more help.